# Entity references reciprocity

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7.43 version. I have two types of content.

> The content type No. 1 - to create Professional Profiles &
>
> The content type no. 2 - to create Departaments.

- First step: I created some nodes using "Departaments": UX, IT, HR, etc.
- Second step: I created an Entity Reference to show these Departaments as a list inside "Professional Profiles".
- Third step: I created a node named "Joe" using "Professional Types". Inside that form I’m able to assign "Joe" in some Departaments. For instance, "IT".

What I would like to achieve is reciprocity in addition. That is, if I go to the form of node "IT", I should see that Joe Doe is marked. But if from "IT" node I uncheck "Joe", this Departament should be unmarked in professional profile of Joe.

I try to achieve it by using two modules: [Entity Reference Backreference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_backreference) and [Corresponding Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) but I have not been able to get it.

Anybody knows how to achieve it?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: [cer](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) does exactly this, it's not so hard to be configured, go to `admin/config/content/cer` and check `BIDIRECTIONAL`, otherwise you'll have to create your own logic so to update the corresponding fields in hooks like node_presave, node_insert, node_delete,even though cer keeps references from deleted entities if I can recall correctly.